# SQL Server Cross Database Query from On-Premises to Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, linked-server

Two SQL Server

1. On-Premises
2. Azure

When I run the T-sql

1. On-Premises only

> Select top 100 * from Orders

The result is very fast as usual.

2. Azure Only

> Select top 100 * from Orders_2

The same, Fast.

3. This is the point.
   No matter what I used "Link-Server" or "OPENDATASOURCE".

> Select top 100 * from Orders a  LEFT OUTER JOIN
>
> **[AZUREDB]**.DB01.dbo.Orders_2 a2  ON a2.ID= a.ID

OR

> Select top 100 * from Orders a  LEFT OUTER JOIN
> **OPENDATASOURCE**('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=AzureDB;User
> ID=XXX;Password=XXX') .DB01.dbo.Orders_2 a2  ON a2.ID= a.ID

It takes a very long time, about 15 mins.
What's happened? and how to fix it?

Comment: For SQL performance question, you must share the query plan, preferably via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is generally a logic flaw - regardless of the location of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Because it needs to pull the whole table from the remote server into the local server and then *afterwards* do the `TOP 100`. If you look at the query plan, which you haven't shown us, you will see that's what is happening.

Instead, filter the remote server's data first before joining.

```sql
Select
  *
from Orders a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP (100)
      *
    FROM [AZUREDB].DB01.dbo.Orders_2
) a2 ON a2.ID = a.ID
```

Whether that works with the desired results, i don't know, as you haven't shown what you want.

The other alternative is to ensure the remote server's table has an index (probably clustered) on `ID`. This means that hopefully your query can just pass 100 rows from your own server to the remote one to join it up.